# pyenv seems to revert to older Python version after terminal restart

Tags: python, bash, macos, pyenv

I am using macOS Sierra. I have problems about using pyenv.
I want to use pyenv. So I added path about pyenv.

$ is shell.

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

[.bash_profile]

```
export PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/pyenv
if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi
if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"; fi
```

and

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

and

```
$ pyenv install 3.6.2
$ pyenv global 3.6.2
$ python -V
(Console Output) Python 3.6.2
```

I restarted the terminal.

```
$ python -V
(Console Output) Python 2.7.10
```

I typed `pyenv global 3.6.2` again on shell, but

```
$ python -V
(Console Output) Python 2.7.10
```

[update ~/.bash_profile]

```
Sangwon-Hong-MacBook-Pro:~ Frodo$ source ~/.bash_profile
Sangwon-Hong-MacBook-Pro:~ Frodo$ python -V
Python 3.6.2
Sangwon-Hong-MacBook-Pro:~ Frodo$ echo $PATH
/Users/Frodo/64bit-Multicore-OS/cross/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.1.0/shims:/usr/local/var/pyenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Frodo/.rvm/bin
```

[restart] : PATH doesn't update.

```
Sangwon-Hong-MacBook-Pro:~ Frodo$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
Sangwon-Hong-MacBook-Pro:~ Frodo$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Frodo/.rvm/bin
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I wasn't quite clear what in your post was input and what was console output. I *think* I've fixed it, but have another look to make sure.

Comment: Where is this `.bash_profile`?  Is it in your home directory (i.e. `~/.bash_profile`)

Comment: Yes, it is in my home directory(/Users/Frodo/).
I found problems.
When I typed source ~/.bash_profile and echo $PATH, then it is updated about pyev path.
But when I restart terminal and echo $PATH, the path about pyenv is not included in $PATH. I don't know why...

Comment: Are you sure your terminal is creating a login shell for a new window? (That tends to be the default on macOS, but perhaps you reconfigured it to create a regular interactive shell to coincide with the typical behavior under Linux.)

Comment: Thank you. It was not default login shell....